# Sorting C++ vector and C# List

Tags: c#, c++, list, vector, compare

I decided to compare speed C++ std::vector with C# List in sorting test.
So I filled  them with 2 700 000 same strings and measured time of sorting.

It looks like this:

C++:

```
std::vector<std::string> CPPList;
std::ifstream file("words-back.txt");

std::string word;
while(std::getline(file, word))
{
    CPPList.push_back(word);
}

file.close();

Profiler profiler;
profiler.Start();

std::sort(CPPList.begin(),CPPList.end ());

profiler.Stop();
```

C#:

```
string[] lista = File.ReadAllLines("words-back.txt").ToArray();

List<string> CSList = new List<string>();
foreach (string element in lista)
{
    CSList.Add(element);
}

Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    CSList.Sort( );
timer.Stop();
```

And results surprised me so much that I had to ask you what is going on. C++ needed 0,7 second while C# 25 seconds.  I did output files with sorted strings for beeing sure that sorting is done correctly and it was correct.

My question is: why C# make this so much longer than C++.

I am sorry, before I ate one zero it's not 270 000  but 2 700 000 string in this file,

Comment: C++ faster than C#? That's odd...

Comment: Please show your actual, **complete** code.  Are you also measuring JIT time?

Comment: What is the question though?

Comment: AFAIK calling a member method for sorting a list, uses a O(n^2) algorithm. Even in C++ STL, if you define `list<int> mylist` and call `mylist.sort()` it takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: I used `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to generate a list of 270,000 strings. Sorting them took me 1.2 seconds on average in a debug build. Your results don't seem accurate at all.

Comment: @BenTrofatter If you don't know how the JIT works, don't post any comments about C#. Thank you.

Comment: I'm with @Siege. I get around 780ms for 270k GUID strings. What's on words-back.txt? Is it sorted by something? Maybe its distribution works fine with STL's algorithm but not List's.

Comment: BTW, I also tried it using LINQ's `OrderBy(s=>s)`, and consistently got results taking about 20% longer than `Sort`, but still usually < 1 second.

Comment: With 2.7mm strings, I get ~10 seconds for `List.Sort` (and ~9.5 sec for `OrderBy`) which is more consistent with your results. Interesting.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan as an excuse to write C++, I wrote a C++ benchmark with results comparable to C# (albeit 3x faster, but no where near approaching the results of @Berserker's). See my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Because I love to waste my time on pointless things like this, here's *my* benchmark results (using the same "guids.txt" that weighed in at around 100mb with 2.7 million GUIDs for both languages):

With C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numStrings = 2700000;
    List<string> strings = new List<string>(numStrings);

    // pre-jit the generic type
    new List<string>(new[] { "str1", "str2" }).Sort();

    using (var fs = File.Open("C:\\guids.txt", FileMode.Open))
    using (var r = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading strings...");
        string str;
        while ((str = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            strings.Add(str);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Beginning sort...");

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    strings.Sort();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds, or " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
}
```

In release build I got ~15 seconds.

In C++:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Loading strings..." << endl;

    int numStrings = 2700000;
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.reserve(numStrings);

    ifstream file("C:\\guids.txt");

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        vec.push_back(line);
    }

    cout << "Starting sort..." << endl;

    unsigned start = clock();
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    unsigned ms = clock() - start;

    int seconds = ms / 1000;

    cout << "Result: " << seconds << " seconds, or" << endl << ms << " milliseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I got about ~5 seconds.

So C++ is roughly 3x faster. The reason C# is slow is probably due to bounds checks on every access to the array that `List<T>` uses internally, which C++ doesn't do, or can more easily optimize away.

Comment: And even the 3x can be optimized away if you want to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146086/Fast-String-Sort-in-C-and-F Thank you for wasting your time, i just waited for someone do do it. :-)

Comment: Btw you forget to call Sort once to avoid measuring JIT time!

Comment: @FelixK. It makes no perceivable difference; we're talking about 2.7 million strings. I'll include it anyway, though. The result is identical.

Comment: Hmm I just copied your code and I have still 25 seconds on c# while on c++ only 0,7 second. Can you try on same file that I am sorting?

Link to file: http://www.2shared.com/document/Cb4lFbCx/words-back.html

Comment: @Berserker using your strings, both had better times: C++ completed in 0.9 seconds, and C# in 8 seconds. It's not quite as dramatic as your tests, but there you go. As for why C# is slower, I'd wager it's due to the millions of bounds checks accessing `List`'s internal array, and the amount of un-inline-able code (`IComparer.Sort`) that `Array.Sort` (called by `List.Sort`) calls to perform its sort. Knowing which tools to use is important; if you really need those 7.1 seconds, you need C++ (or implement a better sort in C#).

Comment: @Berserker also, are you running your C# tests with a debugger attached (tip: dont't)? And which CLR version are you targeting? All my tests were ran on 4.0.

Comment: It's not on debug mode, and i have installed .NET 4.0.:)

Comment: @Berserker ensure you're launching without the debugger attached by going to (in VS) 'Debug' -> 'Start Without Debugging'. The debugger is still attached in release build otherwise.

Comment: This is how I am starting all time :) "Start without debugging" Maybe it is how it should be, this 25 seconds?